# Broadcast text from arguments

Tags: java, bukkit

I would like to make a broadcast command. When the `/broadcast This is a test` is run, it would broadcast *This is a test* (with spaces) in-game. I've tried using:

```
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5] + " " + args[6] + " " + args[7] + " " + args[8] + " " + args[9] + " " + args[10] + " " + args[11] + " " + args[12] + " " + args[13] + " " + args[14]);
```

But I know it is wrong. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 8, you can use a handy method with `Collectors`:

```
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(
    ChatColor.RED + Arrays.stream(args)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
);
```

Otherwise, iterate through the array and use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the elements:

```
if (args.length == 0)
    // Premature return instead of using if-else
    // to reduce cyclomatic complexity.
    return false;
if (args.length == 1) {
    // fast path
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[0]);
    return false;
}

StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(args[0]);
for (String each : args)
    message.append(" ").append(each);
String broadcast = message.deleteCharAt(0).toString();
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + broadcast);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5] + " " + args[6] + " " + args[7] + " " + args[8] + " " + args[9] + " " + args[10] + " " + args[11] + " " + args[12] + " " + args[13] + " " + args[14]);
```

Will only work if there are exactly 15 arguments. If there are less arguments, it will throw an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), because you are trying to access part of the array that does not exist. If there are more arguments, the code will only print the first 15 arguments, and the rest will be ignored.

To fix this, you need to loop through all of the arguments:

```
for(String argument : args)
```

Then, you need to add the argument to the broadcast message, along with a space:

```
message+=argument;
message+=" ";
```

To avoid an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), you should also check if there is at least 1 argument:

```
if(args.length >= 1)
```

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
if (args.length >= 1) { // make sure there is at least 1 argument to avoid an ArrayOutOfBoundsException
    String message = ""; // initialize the "message" variable
    for (String argument : args) { // loop through all of the arguments
        message += argument; // add the argument to the message
        message += " "; // add a space to the message
    }

    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + message); // broadcast the message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that ended up working:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    String broadcast = "";
    for (String message : args) {
        broadcast = (broadcast + message + " ");
    }
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "]" + ChatColor.RED + broadcast);
}
```